# Find the mean of two rows in of a 42 by 4 matrix

Tags: matlab, mean

I want to find the mean of 1st and 22nd row, the 2nd and 23rd row and so on of a 42-by-4 matrix. The first and 22nd rows are:

```
0 0 -30 -2.49000000000000

0 0 -30 -2.38000000000000
```

How can I find the mean of each column in these two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the mean of each colum of the two rows you can use something like

```
mean(t([1,22],:));
```

this will result to

0         0  -30.0000   -2.4350

Comment: How can I write a for loop to calculate the average of 1st and 2nd row,3rd and 4th row.

Comment: for i = 1:2:length(array)  mean(array([i i+1],:)); end

Answer (score 4):

MATLAB has a special syntax for indexing matrices, and you can learn about that by typing

```
   help :
```

Now, suppose your matrix is

```
   M = randn(42,4);  %generating a random matrix with 42 rows and 4 columns
```

Then you can compute the mean of the desired rows using a simple add and average:

```
   rowmeans =  ( M(1:21,:) + M(22:end,:) ) / 2;
```

which will produce a matrix containing 21 rows and 4 columns, where each row is the desired average.

More generally, for averaging the top half and bottom half of a matrix that has an even number of rows:

```
   rowmeans =  ( M(1:end/2,:) + M(end/2+1:end,:) ) / 2;
```

You might also want to learn about the `end` keyword in MATLAB:

```
   help end
```